# Installing @angular/material using Package.json

Tags: asp.net, angular, package.json

i am very new to AngularJS and Angular 4. i want to know whether it is possible to install @angular/material using package.json and systemjs.config.js.

if yes, how and if no what is other way to do the same.

please help.

Comment: read their documentation please

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just follow the steps that they have on their getting started page [link](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). (Configuring systemjs is last step)